# What's the use of 'typedef in C'?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

There are 3 versions of a header file.

version 1:

```
typedef struct node
{
    void* dataPtr;
    struct node* link;
} NODE;
```

version 2: without old type name 'node' (typedef oldTypeName newTypeName)

```
typedef struct
{
    void* dataPtr;
    struct* link;
} NODE;
```

version 3: without typedef

```
struct
{
    void* dataPtr;
    struct* link;
} NODE;
```

According to [C : typedef struct name {...}; VS typedef struct{...} name;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720223/c-typedef-struct-name-vs-typedef-struct-name),
version 1's defining 'node' is superfluous and I changed it to version 2 and it worked fine.

According to this answer again, when not using 'typedef', one cannot reuse 'NODE'.

However, codes that use this version 3 header file worked just fine. (NODE was used two three times.)

This is the code:

```
/* Create a list with two linked nodes.*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "version3.h"                      //Header file

int main (void)
{
//Local Definitions
    int* newData;
    int* nodeData;
    NODE* node;

// Statements
    newData = (int*)malloc (sizeof (int));
    *newData = 7;
    node = createNode(newData);

    newData = (int*)malloc (sizeof (int));
    *newData = 75;
    node->link = createNode(newData);

    nodeData = (int*)node->dataPtr;
    printf ("Data from node 1: %d\n", *nodeData);

    nodeData = (int*)node->link->dataPtr;
    printf ("Data from node 2: %d\n", *nodeData);
    return 0;
}       //main
```

What's the use of 'typedef' in this situation? (assuming that here I reused NODE. -> if this assumption is not true, please tell me why. I'm not familiar with C language.)

Comment: typedef defines a new type, which you can use for more than one instance. Did you try searching for other answers to this question here?

Comment: The line `struct* link;` doesn't compile. Neither version 2 nor version 3 works because neither one compiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`typedef` is used to give a new name to a type. When your third version of `struct` is used then it just declare `NODE` of type `struct{ void* dataPtr; struct* link;}`. Now what would you do if you have to declare another variable of same type as of `NODE`? There is only one option, you have to declare it along with `NODE` otherwise they are incompatible.
Two structure are compatible if they are declared at same time or if they are declared using structure tag or the same type name (using `typedef`).

Answer (score 3):

The following code **does not** create a type. It creates an object named `NODE` that has an anonymous struct as it's type.

```
struct {
    void* dataPtr;
    void* link;
} NODE;

int main() {
}
```

I find it difficult to believe that the code in your question compiles.