# Cross referencing typedef structs

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I have 2 type definitions of structs, `ARRAY` and `OBJECT`.

`ARRAY` has elements in in that are `OBJECT`. `OBJECT` (when it's `TYPE` is `COMPLEX`) has array of it's children

```
enum {
      INT,
      FLOAT,
      STRING,
      CHAR,
      COMPLEX
} typedef TYPE;

struct {
  TYPE type;
  ARRAY children;
  char name[50];
} typedef OBJECT;

struct {
  OBJECT* elements;
  int size;
} typedef ARRAY;
```

I want to create these structs but that's not possible because each one depends on the definition of the other. I get this error:

```
t.c:11:3: error: unknown type name 'ARRAY'
  ARRAY children;
  ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: That's a strange syntax you have there. Not knowing about forward declarations is half of your problem.

Comment: @DeiDei I know what they are. I dont know how to use them here.

Comment: Apart from the invalid syntax, you need to declare at least your object struct with a tag so that you can forward declare it.

Comment: To better understand what you are doing with `typedef` and `struct`, I suggest reading [C : typedef struct name {…}; VS typedef struct{…} name;](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23660072/6320039)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to declare the `TYPE`, `OBJECT` and `ARRAY` type aliases, using a forward declaration of the `OBJECT` type alias to avoid circular dependencies. This requires the associated `struct` type to be declared with a tag that will match its later complete declaration.

```
typedef enum {
    INT,
    FLOAT,
    STRING,
    CHAR,
    COMPLEX
} TYPE;

// incomplete declaration of struct _OBJECT and OBJECT
typedef struct _OBJECT OBJECT;

typedef struct {
    OBJECT* elements;
    int size;
} ARRAY;

// complete declaration of struct _OBJECT
struct _OBJECT {
    TYPE type;
    ARRAY children;
    char name[50];
};
```

Comment: I think this forms an argument that `typedef`ing all your types is bad.